# Google Adwords: {creative} parameter always returns "zero" even if it's an active reviewed Ad

Tags: templates, tracking, ads, google-ads-api

I'm new using Google AdWords API, and we are building an intermediate layer to collect some statistics for the Ad Clicks.

We are trying to add a tracking template URL to an Ad, and using some attributes, something like:
http://www.example.com/?url={lpurl}&cid={campaignid}&gid={adgroupid}&adid={creative}

When I click the "Test" button, it all the tokens gets replaced by the right value, except for the {creative} token does not get replaced by the Ad ID and it gets replaced by 0

What are we doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: Interesting, I tried the same and also was shown a creative ID of zero when using the "Test" button. I tend to believe that this is a limitation of the testing feature—when you run your ads, the creative ValueTrack parameter should be filled out correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are testing on your first ad, try adding another and you will see adid=1